# Not able to view the navigation bar in Android app despite including the necessary syntaxes

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I tried to include the navigation bar in an existing app. but the contens of the activity is also not shown on inclusion 
this is my code --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".common.components.main.HomeActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_toolbar" />
        <include layout="@layout/activity_home_contents" />


    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the contents of my nav_toolbar layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Similarly I have activity_home_contents in scroll view as

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@color/white"
android:scrollbars="none"
>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    tools:context=".common.components.main.HomeActivity">

     ......
```

And code snipplet from HomeActivity.java is

```
.....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    floodEvacApplication = (FloodEvacApplication) 
    getApplicationContext();
    lastAddress = floodEvacApplication.getLatestAddress();
    if (lastAddress == null) {
        initGoogleAPI();
    }


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
   findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
   ......
```

I tried various ways avaliable online and searched online but couldn't able to display the activity_home_contents also but if I remove the navigation drawer and display the activiy_home then I am able to display it.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: You can add predefined NavigationDrawerActivity from Android Studio, Go to File menu->New->Activity->Navigation Drawer Activity.
It will help you with predefined layouts and modify according to your needs.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line under android.support.design.widget.NavigationView in Drawer's XML:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```